# Enable Users to Build Dynamic Text File Layouts for Import/Export without the Need for a Programmer to Hard-code them in SQL Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, import, export, dynamic-sql

In our organization we frequently import and export text files from/to various organizations (trading partners). Our trading partners have file layout requirements such as fixed width vs delimited, what fields to include in the files, if the files contain any loops, headers, trailers, etc. and we've been hard-coding those requirements into stored procedures. Each file layout typically has its own dedicated stored procedure. We have hundreds of file layouts and therefore hundreds of stored procedures. We use Microsoft SQL Server.

What we would like to do is be able to specify those layout requirements in tables so that end users could "build" the file layouts using a form or something and not have to request that a programmer create new stored procedures and hard-code these layout requirements every time we have a new file layout. In other words, we want the file layout requirements to be stored in tables instead of hard-coded in stored procedures.

Do y'all have any good advice or documentation for how best to accomplish this? Would we need to have a stored procedure build dynamic SQL based on configuration rows in tables? Should we use a C# CLR routine? We've scoured the web and can't find anything on this topic.

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Look at ETL Tools.

Comment: What method(s) do your stored procs use to read the files?

Comment: We just bulk import and export files using BCP.